# XQuery expression has an unexpected token "/"

Tags: db2, xquery-3.0

So I'm working with DB2 from command line. Before you ask, yes, it is running with admin rights and I can connect to the database and db2 is running.

Here is my input in the cmd:

```
db2 xquery declare default element namespace "http://tpox-benchmark.com/security"; for $s in db2-fn:xmlcolumn("SECURITY.SDOC")/Security where $s/Symbol= "BCIIPRC" return $s
```

And this is the error that I get:

> SQL16002N An XQuery expression has unexpected token "/"  following
>   "pace http:". Expected tokens may include: ":". Error
>   QName=err:XPST0003. SQLSTATE=10505

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And your question is?

Your shell may be stripping away those double quotes. Try enclosing the entire xquery statement in single quotes:

```
db2 'xquery declare ... return $s'
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the " with ' and it works now. Thanks @mustaccio for the suggestion.

```
db2 xquery declare default element namespace "http://tpox-benchmark.com/security"; for $s in db2-fn:xmlcolumn("SECURITY.SDOC")/Security where $s/Symbol= "BCIIPRC" return $s
```